# Doxygen lists within exception tags render incorrectly

Tags: documentation, doxygen

A list in the main doc of a symbol...

```
/**
 * - foo
 * - bar
 * - wah
 */
```

renders nicely in Doxygen as bullet points:

[image]

The Doxygen [documentation](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdexception) for the `exception` tag includes:

> The text of the paragraph [after @exception] has no special internal structure. All visual enhancement commands may be used inside the paragraph. Each exception description will start on a new line. The \exception description ends when a blank line or some other sectioning command is encountered.

Despite that "all visual enhancement commands may be used inside the paragraph", it seems that lists cannot render correctly inside `exception` tags, possibly due to the strict handling of line ends.

The same list, inside an `exception` tag...

```
/**
 * @exception myError
 * - foo 
 * - bar 
 * - wah
 */
```

renders as bullet points strangely spaced apart:

[image]

It is possible Doxygen interprets each element of the list as a separate "exception description", and as such, separates them by newlines.
How can I avoid this behaviour, such that lists render as bullet points in the same way they do in the main doc?

I'm using **Doxygen** **1.8.13** on **Ubuntu** **18.04**. [Here](https://pastebin.com/MmuTQdTx) is my doxygen config file which renders the below MWE incorrectly:

```
/**
 * - foo 
 * - bar 
 * - wah
 * @exception myError
 * - foo 
 * - bar 
 * - wah
 */
void myFunc();
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Please give a minimal, complete example showing the problem  as with the given information I've not been able to reproduce the problem (with a default  settings file and after correcting `/*` to `/**``). Also specify the settings that are different from the default settings (`doxygen -x` output for the newer versioins)

Comment: @albert So there's hope! I've updated my question with versions and MWE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doxygen 1.8.13 is already a bit older (December 2016), I certainly advise to update to the current version 1.9.1 but this is not the cause of the problem/.

The provided Doxyfile is not really minimal and contains a lot of project specific stuff not relevant for the issue at hand. A doxyfile with

```
EXTRACT_ALL=YES
QUIET=YES
```

is sufficient.

When running the given input we get:

[image]

The question is where do we want to have the word `Exceptions` and the subsequent list items?
Currently the first set of list items is not terminated till after the second `- wuh` and the `Exceptions` is seen as part of the first `wuh` list item and the second `foo` is seen as a level 1 list item hence the above shown output.

A solution (not the extra space before the items after the `@exception` making it here a second level list):

```
/**
 * - foo
 * - bar
 * - wah
 * @exception myError
 *   - foo
 *   - bar
 *   - wah
 */
void myFunc();
```

result:

[image]

Probably the wanted solution (note the empty line before `@exception` which terminates the first list):

```
/**
 * - foo
 * - bar
 * - wah
 *
 * @exception myError
 * - foo
 * - bar
 * - wah
 */
void myFunc();
~
```

result:

[image]

(I ran everything with the 1.8.13 version)

Comment: Neither of your solutions render correctly on my system; perhaps something else in my config is at play - I would shrink it to the relevant part if I had the foresight to know which it were

Comment: Which image / solution would be correct for you from the possibilities I showed? and what do you get when you run it with your setup? (added this information as an edit to the question). As mentioned before in your Doxyfile there are a number of system dependencies that I had to disable, good candidates for giving problems are `HTML_HEADER`, `HTML_FOOTER`, `HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET`, `HTML_EXTRA_FILES`, `LAYOUT_FILE` so for tests disable these and work from there.

Comment: Good thinking. Indeed, my `HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET` included CSS `table{ white-space:pre-wrap !important; }` which caused the issue.